# Can't get to boxes to align next to each other when there is a button with a link

Tags: html, css, django

I want to align two boxes horizontal to each other, but when i add a button with a link. The are align vertical.

```css
.box-element{
    box-shadow:hsl(0, 0%, 80%) 0 0 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element">
                <hr>
                <h3>Order Summary</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{% static 'images/placeholder.png' %}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>Product 1</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>$20.00</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>x2</p></div>
                </div>
                <h5>Items:   2</h5>
                <h5>Total:   $4</h5>
            </div>
   </div>
```

result:
 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs67Y.png

```html
   <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element">
            <a href="{% url 'cart' %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark"  >&#x2190; Back to Cart</a>
                <hr>
                <h3>Order Summary</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{% static 'images/placeholder.png' %}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>Product 1</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>$20.00</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>x2</p></div>
                </div>
                <h5>Items:   2</h5>
                <h5>Total:   $4</h5>
            </div>
   </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5oxQ.png)

thank you in advanced:)

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather by the code you provided, I believe adding the code below ought to fix the layout to where the two boxes are aligned horizontally even with the button.

```
.col-lg-6 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: like this:

<div class="col-lg-6 { display: inline-block;}">
   <div class="box-element">
?:)

Comment: Jian, do you have your html and css in separate files?

Comment: Then I would just add the `display: inline block` in the css file inside `.col-lg-6`.